# ORA-01722: invalid number but only when query used as subquery

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

A query, like so:

```
SELECT SUM(col1 * col3) AS total, col2
FROM table1
GROUP BY col2
```

works as expected when run individually.

For reference:

```
table1.col1 -- float
table1.col2 -- varchar2
table1.col3 -- float
```

When this query is moved to a subquery, I get an ORA-01722 error, with reference to the "col2" position in the select clause. The larger query looks like this:

```
SELECT col3, subquery1.total
FROM table3
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(table1.col1 * table1.col3) AS total, table.1col2
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY table1.col2
) subquery1 ON table3.col3 = subquery1.col2
```

For reference:

```
table3.col3 -- varchar2
```

It may also be worth noting that I have another query, from *table2* that has the same structure as *table1*.  If I use the subquery from table2, it works. It never works when using table1.

There is no concatenation, the data types match, the query works by itself... I'm at a loss here.  What else should I be looking for?  What painfully obvious problem is staring me in the face?

(I didn't choose or make the table structures and can't change them, so answers to that end will unfortunately not be helpful.)

Comment: I think the problem is due to `ON table3.col3 = subquery1.col2` where col3 -> float and col2 -> varchar2.

Comment: Just for fun, assign aliases to `table1` and `table3` and use them in all the column references in your query.  E.g., `SUM(t1.col1 * t1.col3)` instead of `SUM(col1*col3)`.  It shouldn't matter in the example you posted, but it may shed some light in your real (and presumably more complicated) query.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan table3.col3 is a varchar2 as is table1.col2 that I'm joining on.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak They actually are aliased in my actual query, mostly because the actual table names are so long. The query itself really is pretty much this simple, frustratingly enough.

Comment: @Davis excuse me, ok table1.col3 != table3.col3

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Yes, sorry, the double use of col3 was a poor choice on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a proper cast of float to char ..

```
  SELECT col3, subquery1.total
  FROM table3
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT SUM(table1.col1 * table1.col3) AS total, table.1col2
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY table1.col2
  ) subquery1 ON to_char(table3.col3)  = subquery1.col2
```

Comment: One of the few casts I didn't try, of course... so table3.col3 and subquery.col2 were both varchar2s.  What's the secret sauce here? :D  I'm so confused. Thanks!

Comment: @davis  .. the secret .. is  look at schema definition  ..look calmly at the definition ... do not look too closely and do not always look at the same things ... because if they are wrong, they will remain wrong ...anyway is better a cast  for number to string respect a cast from string to number